# Given a URI, which EndPoint/Dataset this URI belongs? How can I know?

Tags: linked-data

Is there a way to know which EndPoint/Dataset a given URI belongs to?

Example:
I have a URI (http://example.something/thing) and I would like to know if there is some endpoint / DumpFile / Dataset, where I can find this URI as Subject, predicate or Object.

This is related to Linked Data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

De facto there is no way to do this with a complete certainty.

You can try performing a GET/HEAD request on a subject URI but that would only work if a publisher follows linked data principles.

Otherwise, as far as RDF is concerned, URIs are just identifiers that may be used without any further limitations.

VoID, however, defines [metadata for access](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/#access) and [URI spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/#pattern) for datasets. But again, it requires support from the dataset published either by having discovery mechanisms, such as a [`void.ttl`](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/#void-file) along the dataset and or via a [`.well-known`](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/#well-known) service, or by adding metadata in the dataset via [`void:inDataset`](https://www.w3.org/TR/void/#discovery-links) predicates.

There is also an experimental way to do this via a [SPORTAL](http://www.sportalproject.org/) project ([paper](http://ciws.cl/media/pdf/sportal-sparql-portal.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, now there is a way, it's called "Where is my URI?"
http://wimu.aksw.org/

The website has more information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.